# Angular 11 Input Validation

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to implement custom validation in Angular 11.

My component.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, PatternValidator } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-microplate',
  templateUrl: './microplate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./microplate.component.css']
})
export class MicroplateComponent {
  columns = new FormControl('', isValid(???));

  isValid(???) {
    return some logic based on the ???;
  }
}
```

My component.html is as follows (without any  tag. Just as shown here):

```
<label for="columns"><b>Columns: </b></label>
<input id="columns" type="text" [formControl]="columns">
```

In the above code, by ??? I mean the value of the columns field, but I don't know how to send the value of the columns field to the isValid() method. I don't know how to do a custom validation even after hours of searching in google. I also want to show an error message in the component.html if the isValid() method returns false, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

defining a custom validator is already well explained in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export function isValid(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    // ??? <--> control.value
  };
}
```

Comment: what should I put instead of `// ??? <--> control.value`?

Answer (score 0):

As written on Angular.io:
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-reactive-forms

You can insert a directive, export it and insert it into a FormControl.

```
this.heroForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
    Validators.required,
    forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
  ])
});
```

forbiddenNameValidator is:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

/** A hero's name can't match the given regular expression */
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? { forbiddenName: { value: control.value } } : null;
  };
}
```

Below is a link with an example of implementation:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m89a31?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts